# Managing complex state in FP

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purely-functional

I want to write a simulation of a multi-entity system. I believe such systems motivated creation of Simula and OOP where each object would maintain its own state and the runtime would manage the the entire system (e.g. stop threads, serialize data).

On the other hand, I would like to have ability to rewind, change the simulation parameters and compare the results. Thus, immutability sounds great (at least up to almost certain garbage collection issues caused by keeping track of possibly redundant data).

However I don't know how to model this. **Does this mean that I must put every interacting entity into a single, huge structure** where each object update would require locating it first?

I'm worried that such approach would affect performance badly because of GC overhead and constant structure traversals as opposed to keeping one fixed address of entity in memory.

**UPDATE**

To clarify, this question asks if there is **any other design option available other than creating a single structure** that contains all possibly interacting entities as a root. Intuitively, such a structure would imply logarithmic single update penalty unless updates are "clustered" somehow to amortize.

Is there a known system where interactions could be modelled differently? For example, like in cold/hot data storage optimization?

After some research, there seems to be a connection with N-body simulation where systems can be clustered but I'm not familiar with it yet. Even so, would that also mean I need to have a single structure of clusters?

Comment: Hmm your question is very vague and broad, it is hard to give you concrete advice. Have you tried any poc? If not just implement the first idea you have an test it.

Comment: [AFRP](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrows-based_Functional_Reactive_Programming) might be a good fit, though it can be a pretty steep learning curve if you are somewhat new to Haskell.  In any case, you probably do need all the objects to be "globally indexed" in some way (RAM is globally indexed, too), and it's worth thinking carefully about what kind of data structure you need.  More details -> more advice.

Comment: An OOP system **is** a huge structure where each object update requires locating it first, it's just that the indirection takes a different form.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think the question is mainly about how much overhead this different form of indirection has

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the people commenting that this is a vague question, I'll still try to address some of the issues put forth.

It's true that there's *some* performance overhead from immutability, because when you use mutable state, you can update some values in-place, whereas with immutable state, some copying has to take place.

It is, however, a common misconception that this is causes problems with big 'object' graphs. It doesn't have to.

Consider a Haskell data structure:

```
data BigDataStructure = BigDataStructure {
    bigChild1 :: AnotherBigDataStructure
  , bigChild2 :: YetAnotherBigDataStructure
  -- more elements go here...
  , bigChildN :: Whatever }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Imagine that each of these child elements are big and complex themselves. If you want to change, say, `bigChild2`, you could write something like:

```
updatedValue = myValue { bigChild2 = updatedChild }
```

When you do that, some data copying takes place, but it's often less that most people think. This expression does create a new `BigDataStructure` record, but it doesn't 'deep copy' any of its values. It just reuses `bigChild1`, `updatedChild`, `bigChildN`, and all the other values, because they're immutable.

In theory (but we'll get back to that in a minute), the flatter your data structures are, the more data sharing should be enabled. If, on the other hand, you have some deeply nested data structures, and you need to update the leafs, you'll need to create a copy of the immediate parents of those leafs, plus the parents of those parents, and their parents as well, all the way to the root. That might be expensive.

That's the theory, though, but we've known for decades that it's impractical to try predict how software will perform. Instead, try to measure it.

While the OP suggest that significant data is involved, it doesn't state how much, and neither does it state the hardware specs of the system that's going to run the simulation. So, as [Eric Lippert explains so well](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), the person who can best answer questions about performance is you.

---

P.S. It's my experience that when I start to encounter performance problems, I need to get creative with how I design my system. Efficient data structures can address many performance issues. This is just as much the case in OOP as it is in FP.